# postbutton fadein when mouseover comment box, but fades out when mouseover postbutton

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want my 'post a comment' button to fade in on mouseover the comment field, but when you go to click the post button, it fades out because the mouse is not over the comment field anymore. for example:

```
$('#comment_field').mouseover(function(){
    $('#post_comment').fadeIn(300);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#post_comment').fadeOut(300);
});
```

The post_comment element is absolutely position over the comment_field element. So I tried to remedy the situation with this:

```
$('#post_comment').mouseover(function(){
            $('#post_comment').show();
        }
```

but javascript poops the bed when I do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
 $('#comment_field').hover(function(){
    $('#post_comment').slideToggle(300);
}, function(){
    $('#post_comment').slideToggle(300);
});
```

I hope. It will works.